# Replace NaN values from DataFrame with values from series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, series

I am trying to implement code which will do the following with pandas.

```py
def fill_in_capabilities(df):
    capacity_means = df.groupby("LV_Name").mean(["LEO_Capa", "GTO_Capa"])

    for row in df:
        if np.isnan(row["LEO_Capa"]):
            row["LEO_Capa"] = capacity_means[row["LV_Name"]]

    return df
```

Basically, for the rows in `df` where the value in the column `"LEO_Capa"` is `NaN`, I would like to replace the value there with a value from the series `capacity_means`, indexed by the value in the column `"LV_Name"` from the df with the missing value. How would one do this with pandas, as the code there does not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function:

```
def fill_in_capabilities(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df[["LEO_Capa", "GTO_Capa"]] = df[["LEO_Capa", "GTO_Capa"]].fillna(
        df.groupby("LV_Name")[["LEO_Capa", "GTO_Capa"]].transform("mean")
    )

    return df


df = fill_in_capabilities(df)
```